# I have created a custom compliance policy in Endpoint manager but the device statuses are 'Error' instead of 'non-compliant' or 'compliant'

Tags: powershell, endpoint, intune

This is the very basic picture I am working with. It doesnt show the device as 'compliant' or 'non-compliant', but rather with 'error' or 'pending'. I noticed backslashes used as escape character in the logs. Could the path be a problem? Please advise.

```
$filePath = "C:\ProgramData\Autodesk\_PennCompliance"
$currentFileName = Get-ChildItem -Path $filePath -Name companyCompliance*.txt
$hash = @{
    FileName = $currentFileName
}
Write-Output $hash
return $hash | ConvertTo-Json -Compress
```

My JSON file has the matching key as in the hashTable 'FileName'

```
{
    "Rules":[
        {
           "SettingName":"FileName",
           "Operator":"IsEquals",
           "DataType":"String",
           "Operand":"PennCompliance_2021-0921.txt",
           "MoreInfoUrl":"https://call4cloud.nl/2021/11/the-last-days-of-custom-compliance/#part1",
           "RemediationStrings":[
              {
                 "Language":"en_US",
                 "Title":"Must update text file suffix.",
                 "Description": "Must update the suffix containing the date (PennCompliance_yyyy-mmdd.txt) of the PennCompliance text file."
              }
           ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Now I am looking for the status of 'Compliant' or 'Not Compliant' but instead see 'error' or 'pending'. I have deployed a Custom compliance policy from a sample and it worked fine so its something with this code. I also looked at the intuneManagementExtension logs at the time it failed.

```
{"PolicyId":"0cb83122-b322-45f5-9ab1-8e75c28ce7f5","UserId":"3dc325b8-6b7b-4b95-9e56-df64471366e0","PolicyHash":null,"Result":3,"ResultDetails":null,"InternalVersion":2,"ErrorCode":0,"ResultType":3,"PreRemediationDetectScriptOutput":"{\"FileName\":{\"value\":\"PennoniCompliance_2021-0921.txt\",\"PSPath\":\"Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\\\\FileSystem::C:\\\\ProgramData\\\\Autodesk\\\\_PennCompliance\\\\PennoniCompliance_2021-0921.txt\",\"PSParentPath\":\"Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\\\\FileSystem::C:\\\\ProgramData\\\\Autodesk\\\\_PennCompliance\",\"PSChildName\":\"PennoniCompliance_2021-0921.txt\",\"PSDrive\":{\"CurrentLocation\":\"WINDOWS\\\\system32\",\"Name\":\"C\",\"Provider\":\"Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\\\\FileSystem\",\"Root\":\"C:\\\\\",\"Description\":\"Windows\",\"MaximumSize\":null,\"Credential\":\"System.Management.Automation.PSCredential\",\"DisplayRoot\":null},\"PSProvider\":{\"ImplementingType\":\"Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.FileSystemProvider\",\"HelpFile\":\"System.Management.Automation.dll-Help.xml\",\"Name\":\"FileSystem\",\"PSSnapIn\":\"Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\",\"ModuleName\":\"Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\",\"Module\":null,\"Description\":\"\",\"Capabilities\":52,\"Home\":\"C:\\\\WINDOWS\\\\system32\\\\config\\\\systemprofile\",\"Drives\":\"C\"},\"PSIsContainer\":false}}","PreRemediationDetectScriptError":null,"RemediationScriptErrorDetails":null,"PostRemediationDetectScriptOutput":null,"PostRemediationDetectScriptError":null,"RemediationStatus":4,"Info":{"RemediationExitCode":null,"FirstDetectExitCode":0,"LastDetectExitCode":null,"ErrorDetails":null},"TargetType":1,"RunAsAccount":1,"AssignmentFilterIds":null,"BiosMetadata":null}
```

I just don't know what to make of it. It looks like the backslash is escaping the absolute path, Im not sure. What I do know is any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting an object back and passing the whole thing to the output. `$currentFileName` could possibly return multiple files, and each of those files has multiple properties.

You can inspect this on your box by passing `$currentFileName` to get member to see what what properties are available:

```
$currentFileName | Get-Member
```

To get back just the file name (of the first result `[0]`) you can do:

```
$currentFileName = (Get-ChildItem -Path $filePath -Name companyCompliance*.txt)[0].Name
```

Just be warned, if Get-ChildItem doesn't return anything, the `[0]` will throw an error. You can use an if block to check the count.

I also removed the Write-Output because that could cause issues.

Here's the full solution:

```
$filePath = "C:\ProgramData\Autodesk\_PennoniCompliance"
$currentFile = Get-ChildItem -Path $filePath -Name companyCompliance*.txt
if($currentFile.Count -ge 1){
  $currentFileName = $currentFile[0].Name
}
else {
  $currentFileName = 'None'
}
$hash = @{
    FileName = $currentFileName
}
return $hash | ConvertTo-Json -Compress
```